# trigger for sending latest jobid and joballocation url in resourceemail

Tags: trigger

```
trigger SendEmail on Opportunity (after insert,after update) {

    Set<Id> setResource=new Set<Id>();
    //Set<Id> setjob=new Set<Id>();
    for(Opportunity opp:Trigger.new){
        if(opp.status__c == 'new'){
            if(opp.Resource__c != null ){
                setResource.add(opp.Resource__c);
                //setjob.add(opp.job__c);
            }
        }
    }

    List<String> lstEmails=new List<String>();

   if(!setResource.isEmpty()){
        List<Resource__c> lstResource= [Select Id,Email__c from Resource__c Where Id IN : setResource];
        if(!lstResource.isEmpty())
        {
            for(Resource__c res:lstResource)
            {
                lstEmails.add(res.Email__c);
            }
        }
    }

    String Body='';

List<jobAllocation__c> lstJob=[Select Id From jobAllocation__c ORDER BY CreatedDate desc limit 1];
  if(!lstJob.isEmpty())
        {
            for(jobAllocation__c job:lstJob){
                body=body+'https://ap2.salesforce.com/'+job.id+'\n';
            }
        }

    if(!lstEmails.isEmpty()){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(lstEmails);   
        mail.setSubject('Response Message');  
        mail.setPlainTextBody(Body);
        mail.setHtmlBody(Body);
        Messaging.SendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i am sending job allocation with jobid but some times it is old and new i want to send only latest jobid and latest job allocation

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is missing a vital component. It needs to determine what context it's running in, whether it's `AfterInsert` or `AfterUpdate`. The logic for each is different.

The layout of the trigger needs to be something like the following:

```
trigger SendEmail on Opportunity (after insert,after update) {

    Set<Id> setResource=new Set<Id>();

    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isNew){

       // run logic to select records to send emails

    }

    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isNew){

      // run logic to COMPARE new and old values of opp.Resource__c to collect records 
     // that you want to send emails on

    }

    // rest of trigger that operates on Opp Ids collected above.


} // end of trigger
```

If you want to make this even better, run the last parts of code in your trigger from classes by calling them and passing the Ids as parameters. For a good example, see the first part of [Trigger Frameworks and Apex Trigger Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices) by Kevin O'Hara that shows how to implement a Trigger Handler Class.

Comment: run logic to COMPARE new and old values of opp.Resource__c to collect record